# Locked out of my bitcoin core wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, passphrase

In 2013 I transferred 5,02 BTC to my Bitcoin Core wallet.
My Bitcoin version v0.8.1.0-g34d62a8-beta QT is version 4.8.4

After the transfer I locked the wallet with a password, wrote the password down and now, after 4 years I wanted to send the bitcoins out but it tells me my password is wrong.

I tried several solutions I found on the internet, none of them worked. Do you know a solution? I use both windows and Linuxmint. The wallet was on a Linuxmint computer installed on an USB-stick.

Answer (score -1):

Actually if he has the password he can use brute Force attack and gain access to the wallet if that didn't slove the problem he should use bip39-standalone input his passphrase get the key and import to another wallet

Comment: Bitcoin Core does not use BIP39.